# Setting the text colour of a UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, datepicker

I need to set the text colour of my Date Picker to white, i have had a look around and have tried to set it by creating a keyPath called "textColor" of type "Color" and then setting the colour, this works fine but the current date stays black. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "Color")
```

Or try

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z1xG.png]

another way to customise  Picker

```
DatePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
DatePicker.setValue(UIColor.greenColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
DatePicker.setValue(0.8, forKeyPath: "alpha")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for this:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
datePicker.performSelector("setHighlightsToday:", withObject:UIColor.whiteColor())
```